# How to initialize the state of a Context before providing it in React/Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

I'm developing a website using Next.jsand I'm using a Layout component.
What I'm trying to do is to wrap the children of my Layout in a Context Provider, but I need to initialize the state of the Context inside the Layout, but outside the provider.

This is the code for my Context:

```
// at contexts/ParametrosContext.js

import { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const ParametrosContext = createContext({});

export const ParametrosProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [parametros, setParametros] = useState({});

    function loadParametrosContext(parametrosObj) {
        setParametros(parametrosObj);
    }

    return (
        <ParametrosContext.Provider value={{ parametros, loadParametrosContext }}>
            { children }
        </ParametrosContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Then, my Layout:

```
// at components/layouts/SiteLayout.js

import { ParametrosContext, ParametrosProvider } from "../../contexts/ParametrosContext";

export default function SiteLayout({ children }) {

    const { loadParametrosContext } = useContext(ParametrosContext);

    if (children.props.ConteudoSite.temParametros)
            loadParametrosContext(children.props.ConteudoSite.Parametros);

    return ( 
        <ParametrosProvider>
            <Header/>
            {
                children
            }
            <Footer/>
        </ParametrosProvider>
    )
}
```

As seen in the SiteLayout component's code, I'm trying to call a function of my Context before wrapping the children in the Provider, because is here in the Layout that I have the data to initialize de Context's state, but this is giving me `TypeError: loadParametrosContext is not a function`.

Is there a correct way to do this what I'm trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useContext get context value from nearest parent provider, since `SiteLayout` is the one rendering the provider, there is no context at that point.

Either the `ParametrosProvider` is renderer as parent of `SiteLayout` or you can use a intermediary component inside `SiteLayout` that use the context

```
const LoadParametros = ({ parametros, children }) => {
  const { loadParametrosContext } = useContext(ParametrosContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loadParametrosContext && parametros) {
     loadParametrosContext(parametros);
    }
  }, [parametros]);

  return children;
}
export default function SiteLayout({ children }) {
  return ( 
    <ParametrosProvider>
       <LoadParametros parametros={children.props.conteudoSite.Parametros}>
         <Header/>
         {children}
         <Footer/>
       </LoadParametros>
    </ParametrosProvider>
  );
}
```